# How do I preserve html as is when using Javascript's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

everything is working fine, decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText) comes back as html from parsing script as checked with alert, no errors in the console, but replacing the html to the editor with

```
retHTML.innerHTML =decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

seems to have a "feature" of translating my html to encoded html(`&` to `&amp;`) etc..
I'm not sure why a command that says it is the inner html would prevent you from actually using html? innerText simply amplifies this rather then returning the html free text as implied. How do I get the returned html back to the div as the html I am requesting?

```
function setHTML(retHTML)
{
retHTML.innerText =retHTML.innerHTML; }

function setTEXT(retHTML)
{
var tmpTXT =encodeURIComponent(retHTML.innerText);
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{ retHTML.innerHTML =decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText);  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","path.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send('send=' + tmpTXT); }
```

test markup as follows

```
<object width="853" height="510">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/iaysTVcounI?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/iaysTVcounI?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="853" height="510" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</object>
```

should be

```
<object width="853" height="510">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/iaysTVcounI?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/iaysTVcounI?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="853" height="510" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</object>
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` is a parser when you write to it and a serialiser when you read, not a simple property that stores text.

When you write to `innerHTML`, it converts the HTML source text into DOM objects like Element, Attr and TextNode. It is these DOM objects that reflect the real live state of the document in the browser window, and *not* anything that looks like HTML source.

On writing, any information that is not significant to the ‘information set’ stored in the DOM is lost. This includes things like case (whether your tag was `<b>` or `<B>`), order of attributes, whitespace inside tags, entity and character references (ie whether you said `café`, `caf&#233;` or `caf&eacute;`—it's all the same to an HTML parser), and much more.

Reading back the `innerHTML` you just wrote will re-serialise the parsed DOM and give you something back that won't necessarily be the same string as what you put in. If you made mistakes in your original HTML, you'll also find that the output has been corrected to reflect what the HTML parser did to be able to read what you put in. So an invalid bare ampersand will necessarily turn into `&amp;`.

(I'm not sure what kind of ‘editor’ you're referring to, but if it's a `<textarea>` then that will additionally fix up `<` to `&lt;` in any HTML you write to it, because a textarea can't contain markup. It's also rather odd and unnecessary that you would be passing back URL-encoded data in a `responseText`; are you sure that's what's happening?)

ETA:

> should be value="http://www.youtube.com/v/iaysTVcounI?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0"

No it shouldn't. That's not valid HTML. Escaping the `&`s to `&amp;` is absolutely the correct, required thing to do.

Comment: the decoding is just a habit when passing data(optional) but to your question, I am using contenteditable elements, parsing for valid html and removing all form and related elements. the markup being sent is a simple youtube <object> with applicable child elements. I'm sure you are aware of amps in youtube markup. I am using an HML5 <section> as my editable region for html to be pasted by the user then onblur sending the innerText to the parser, returning the afore mentioned return to the <section> and rendering. I have added the code to my original post.

Comment: Can you give an example of what content you are trying to write to `innerHTML` and how the results differ from what you expected? If you are talking about the `&`s in the URL attributes of an `<object>` then they definitely must be written as `&amp;` as otherwise the markup is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is kinda ghetto but ultimately the following will be my fix. I recomend this as an alternative to innerHTML for literal replacement of the string.

```
retHTML.innerHTML ='';  
retHTML.execCommand('insertHTML',false,xmlhttp.responseText);
```